Laravel returns json page after I have installed laravel breeze api
Please help me to decipher this problem. After I have installed breeze api Laravel returns a Json page as shown below:Json error page
I tried other ports but did not succeed. Larvel returned port not found and specified messages.
I also tried to delete the api file but things went berserk with errors.

It's normal. The route / is already defined in the web.php that returns a json.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid using screenshots or images of code/errors; it would be better if you could paste the actual text into your question. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557 for more.
